# How to show Shopping cart items in layout icon

Tags: asp.net-core, shopping-cart

How Can I show Items which are in my shopping cart in the Layout Icon as seen in the picture:
Note: MVP item is a static data just for explaination.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFCyr.jpg

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community! Please show your effort to solve this first and tell us what specific problem you're running into.

Comment: The problem is that I can't add any model to my layout so I can't use session to move the item .

Comment: @ahmedmegahed are you using session for create your cart system?

Comment: @PritomSarkar Yes I do, and it works but I can't use it in layout as shown in the picture.

Comment: @ahmedmegahed I mean, you failed to use the session in your layout page to show your cart icon with implementation? or do you want to hover over the cart then see what value is in your session data like your posted picture?

Comment: @PritomSarkar I want to hover over the cart then seen what value is in my session data. that is it as you said.

Comment: @ahmedmegahed You should try something, then post your code where you faced problems as per your requirements. you should try first. and read this for ask good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Share your code so that we can assist you quicker